# vue @click function on ::after css element - close btn

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm making a template where I can't add unnecessary HTML items.
I want to make a close button on hover, but it needed to be a `::after` element in CSS as you can see in this image.

[image]

I need to do a VUE @click method on the `::after` element in CSS or select the `::after` element so I can run a function when I click on the close button

anybody a solution?

Comment: You cannot add events to any pesudo element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible(almost)! Pseudo-elements are not part of the DOM. You can't bind any events directly to them.
However you can do a trick: add some child element without any content and bind click event to that element. Use `:after` just to show your close button.